# How to create a main php file so other php files can fill in the blanks?

Tags: php, html

I am busy with practising how to create a website. Now I would like to do it in a way that feels right for me. But at the moment I am failing to create a main page where I am later able to fill in the blanks. With the title it was easy and I succeeded in setting the title on different pages. But when I try to set the content of the complete page, I fail.

This would be my page for filling in the blanks:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <?php require 'navigation.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php $content ?>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
<?php require 'footer.php'; ?>
</html>
```

The code below will be my index page. If I would set my $content as I did below it works, but I am not content with this solution cause the part behind the equals-sign will be seen as a string and it does not feel neat.

```
<?php $title = "Home";?>
<?php $content = "<div class='container bg-image'></div>" ?>


<?php require '..\resources\views\main.php';?>
```

So my question is can I do this in a better way? And how would I do that?

Comment: Are you aware that u forgot ';' twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage in learning how to write PHP, i would suggest including files based on your whereabouts on the page.

But before doing so, i would like to point out that you are not echoing the content in your code. You wrote `<?php $content; ?>` but should instead write `<?php echo $content; ?>` for the current approach.

**Now, back to my suggestion:**
Let's have this file structure:

```
/content/home.php
/content/about.php
/includes/navigation.php
/index.php
```

Each file in the `content` folder can for practise just contain raw HTML which you want to display where you for now have `<?php echo $content; ?>`

Alright, let's open index.php

```
<?php
// Content of index.php
$defaultpage = 'home';

// We would like to display different pages based on the url
// Use the global get variable to figure out which page we want to display
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : $defaultpage;
// Here i used a short syntax for if and else. This code above is equal to:
//
// if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
//    $page = $_GET['page'];
// } else {
//    $page = $defaultpage;
// }

// Hardcoded list of available pages + the title each page should show
$pages = [
    'home' => [
        'title' => 'Welcome to my site',
        'file' => 'home.php'
    ],
    'about' => [
        'title' => 'About me',
        'file' => 'about.php'
    ]
];

// See if the requesed page is a available page by looking inside $pages
if (isset($pages[$page])) {
    $page = $pages[$page];
}
else {
    $page = $pages[$defaultpage];
}
// $page is now overwritten with an associative array containing
// both 'title' and 'file' for content.

// Let us prepare a variable containing the requested page.
$file = dirname(__FILE__)."/contents/".$page['file'].".php";

// If the file doesn't exist, stop execution with an error message
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    exit('<h1>Page not found');
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title><?php echo $page['title']; ?></title>
    <?php require 'navigation.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div id="content">
    <?php include($file); ?>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why you have included you navigation file in the head tag, but i assume you just misplaced it.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for my problem. It is exactly what I was looking for. I only have one question, why do you think my navigation file is misplaced? It is only the file where my navigation bar is in and normally the navigationbar gets placed in the head right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The <body> should contain everything which is going to be seen on the site. The <head> should contain <meta> tags and such. Loading og styling files and scripts is also ment for head, but script tags is often placed in the end of <body> so everything is loaded when scripts is running.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<?php include 'nameOfFile.php'?>` to include a php file in another

Answer (score 0):

This can be used it will work find i guess..

```
    <?php
      include('test.php') //this is how you can add an external php 

      /*but its recommended to use require rather than include as it                                
      throws error to the browser which is really a serious threat*/

     require('test.php')

   ?>
```

> All the best..!!!